This app is blocked" error message - iPhone 3rd party calendar app - can I create Google Cloud OAuth project and change permissions to solve it?
Google: This app is blocked
Google: This app is blocked
I am getting this message when trying to login from an Calendar app on iPhone. The app doesn't have any more updates, the developer abandoned it but I still like to continue using it. However, I am no longer able to login to Google calendar. I understand the issue is with Google not allowing access to older apps to my account. My question is if there is a solution by configuring google cloud by adding an Auth project.
I am not expert in google cloud or technical questions but I have setup a few google cloud apps eg for photos and OCR or TTS in the past so while its not easy I will try.
But before I attempt anything I want to know if it makes even sense. Here is some info about how to setup the access in google cloud for the apps:
https://groups.google.com/g/adwords-api/c/kAS5ScmeCqw?pli=1
https://groups.google.com/g/adwords-api/c/kAS5ScmeCqw?pli=1
https://support.google.com/a/answer/7281227#reviewapps&restrictaccess&trustorlimit&homegrown&blockedmessage
The solution says: create a Google Cloud Platform Project --> Create the Oauth Screen with the right scope ---> Change GCP Project ID in the Script Settings.
So my question, can this be done for an 3rd party app on iOS? Or is the solution meant for my own apps. And how would I get the application ID from the calendar app on iPhone?

The steps can only be followed by the owner of the application.
As they need to be applied at the Google Cloud project that holds the app's current OAuth client id.
So I wouldn't spent much more time trying to fix the app's issue.
Your only such option would be if the app happened to be open source (unlikely for iOS apps), then you could create your own gcp project, oauth client and apps store listing for it.
